# ExtJS updating progress bar from URL get

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs-mvc

I am using ExtJS 3.4.0 ( v 4.0 is not an option at this time )  and attempting to update a progress bar based on the results of an Ajax request. However JS is not my forte.

I have examined the samples on the dev forums and been able to get everything working except the updating based on the actual status .

I have confirmed that my ajax request/responses are happening . However they only happen once per step rather then 1 per 1/2 second. The status is changing on the controller side.

Essentially what I need is for the progress bar to only move from step to step ONLY when the status has changed and to otherwise stay active but holding on the current step. Once the progress bar has started it should send the ajax request for status 1 per second.

Can anyone see where i have gone off track ?

*orignal Ext example located here [Ext example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/simple-widgets/progress-bar.html)

JS code follows

```
var mystatus="";

Ext.onReady(function(){
    var pbar1 = new Ext.ProgressBar({
       text:'Initializing...'
    });
    var count = 0;
    mystatus=null;
    var btn1 = Ext.get('btn1');
                btn1.dom.disabled = false;
   //setup request 
   Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: './account/getStatus',
        method:'GET',
        success: function ( result, request ) { 

                mystatus =Ext.decode(result.responseText).status;
                count =Ext.decode(result.responseText).steps; 
        },
        failure: function ( result, request) { 
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
        } 
    });


    btn1.on('click', function(){
    Ext.fly('p1text').update('Working');        
        if (!pbar1.rendered){
            pbar1.render('p1');
        }else{
            pbar1.text = 'Initializing...';
            pbar1.show();
        }


        Runner.run(pbar1, Ext.get('btn1'), count, function(){
            pbar1.reset(true);
            Ext.fly('p1text').update('Done.').show();
        });


    });



});

var Runner = function(){
    var f = function(v, pbar, btn, count,cb){
        return function(){
            if(v > count){
                btn.dom.disabled = false;
                cb();
            }else{ 

             /// i think this is the block that is either wrong or in the wrong place   
             curStatus=mystatus.toString();
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: './account/getStatus',
                    method:'GET',
                    success: function ( result, request ) { 
                            mystatus =Ext.decode(result.responseText).status;
                    },
                    failure: function ( result, request) { 
                            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
                    } 
                });

                    if (curStatus!=mystatus){
                        pbar.updateProgress(v/count,'Working on '+mystatus+ ' Step ' + v + ' of '+count+'...');
                    }
                }
            }
       };
       return {
        run : function(pbar, btn, count, cb){
            btn.dom.disabled = true;
            var ms = 5000/count;
            for(var i = 1; i < (count+2); i++){
               setTimeout(f(i, pbar, btn, count, cb), i*ms);
            }
        }
    }


    }();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method is sophisticated too much. Instead I suggest that your server returns not only status but current step and total ammount of steps on each request.

So, asumming your server returns responses like this:

```
{
  "status": "My status for step №2",
  "steps": "6", // total ammount of step
  "step": "2" //current step
}
```

You can modify your code to something like this

```
btn1.on('click', function() {
  //some code here

  run(pbar1, Ext.get('btn1'), function() {
    pbar1.reset(true);
    Ext.fly('p1text').update('Done.').show();
  });
}
...
...
...
var run = function(pbar, btn, cb) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: './account/getStatus',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(result, request) {
            //alert(result.responseText);
            var json = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
            pbar.updateProgress(json.step / json.steps, 'Working on ' + json.status + ' Step ' + json.step + ' of ' + json.steps + '...');
            if (json.step < json.steps) setTimeout(function() {
                run(pbar, btn, cb, step + 1);
            }, 200);
            else {
                btn.dom.disabled = false;
                cb();
            }
        },
        failure: function(result, request) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/QzMVH/4/) I've made example for you using [jsfiddle testing ajax requests](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).

Comment: Hmm I think this might be it. Let me run some test and get back to you

Comment: Accepted. I have not got it working yet but you have put me on the right track. Also this is one of the most comprehensive answers I have seen . Thanks

Comment: It seems that if the runner request fails the looping checks stop. Any ideas on how to change that so it trys every 200ms ?